# Weird UI problem when modal view is dismissed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, user-interface, uinavigationcontroller

As shown in the screenshot below, i have a UITableView with some info and upon selecting a row an ABUnknownPersonViewController is invoked. In order to be able to able to dismiss that and go back to the UITableView I have this code:

```
ABUnknownPersonViewController *unknownPersonView = [[[ABUnknownPersonViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

[unknownPersonView setUnknownPersonViewDelegate:self];
[unknownPersonView setDisplayedPerson:personRecord];
[unknownPersonView setAllowsAddingToAddressBook:YES];

UIBarButtonItem *anotherButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Επιστροφή" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                 target:self action:@selector(goBackToView)];

unknownPersonView.navigationItem.title = @"Προσθήκη στις επαφές";
unknownPersonView.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = anotherButton;

navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:unknownPersonView] autorelease];
//navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self] autorelease];
//self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = anotherButton;

[self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
} // didSelectRowAtIndexPath ends here

- (IBAction)goBackToView {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
- (void)unknownPersonViewController:(ABUnknownPersonViewController *)unknownPersonView didResolveToPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {
//  CallerIDAppDelegate *delegate = (CallerIDAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];


}
```

The problem (as you can see) is that when the ABUnknownPersonViewController is dismissed by the "Επιστροφή" button, which is "Back" actually, the view holding the tableView and the blue UIButton is moved a couple of pixels to the bottom!

Any help on what could be causing this?

[Screenshot http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/1237004/problem.jpg](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/1237004/problem.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that adding this line:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

in my viewWillAppear: made the view not to move when the modal view controller is dismissed. However now the initial position was already slightly dislocated to the bottom but fixed it by moving all the outles in IB to the top so it looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

Debug this by checking your view's frame in `-viewWillAppear`, `-viewDidAppear`, `-viewWillDisappear`, and `-viewDidDisappear`.

Also check the view's `autoresizingMask`, and the parent view's `autoresizesSubviews` property.

Comment: Hi, thanx for answering. Will check the view's frame when I have time tomorrow. I am not sure about autoresizingMask and autoresizesSubviews. I present the views using a window... what values should these two properties have? I think i've seen some options in Interface Builder too. Should they be checked or unchecked?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I see the value of setting up a navigation controller here. You could just present the `ABUnknownPersonViewController` with `[self presentModalViewController: unknownPersonView]`;. If you're doing it for the sake of picking up the visual navigation bar with the back button, then just add a nav bar and button to the unknown person view.

It seems like a mixed metaphor to be creating a `UINavigationController` but then not using its usual navigation methods (e.g., `pushViewController:animated:` and `popViewControllerAnimated:`) and instead using the modal methods inherited from `UIViewController`.

Comment: Hi, thanx for answering. Its cleary stated in Apple's docs (in an *Important* note actually) that such kind of modal views, like ABUnknownPersonView Controller need to be invoked from within a navigation controller to work properly.

Comment: Still, invalidname is right. The "right" way for this is to present a modal view controller. You just have to create an additional NavigationController with your UnknownPersonViewController as the root view controller, and present the navigation controller modally. An example is Apple's own adress book app where this happens if you tap on the button to add a person.